# R: data.table- Adding a variable to a list of data tables that holds the name of each table in the list

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently working in R with data.table and am trying to add a variable "data_set" to a list of data tables that holds the name of that item in the list.

For example - The list of tables is med, symp, and care and I would like to add the variable data_set to each table where in data table med, "data_set" would equal "med" and in data table symp, "data_set" would equal "symp". I know I can use lapply for this, but I'm stuck on how to store the name of each table in the "data_set" variable. I know it would go something like this....

```
   tables<-c("med", "symp", "care")
   tables_1<-lapply(mget(tables),function(x)x[, data_set:=…...])
```

How can I reference and store the name of each data table in the "data_set" variable?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you can use `Map` instead of `lapply` here.

```r
med <- data.table(a=1); symp <- data.table(b=1); care <- data.table(d=1)
tables <- c("med", "symp", "care")
tables_1 <- Map(function(x, nm) copy(x)[, data_set := nm], mget(tables), tables)
tables_1
# $med
#    a data_set
# 1: 1      med
# $symp
#    b data_set
# 1: 1     symp
# $care
#    d data_set
# 1: 1     care
```

I use `copy` *inferring* that your use of `lapply` was not needing side-effect. Without `copy`, your global-env variables (`med`, `symp`, `care`) would have had the column added as well. This might be desired and/or acceptable, in which case remove `copy` to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: This should work, but I get the error- Error in mget(tables) : invalid first argument

Comment: If `tables` is a character vector and all of those names exist in the current environment, then it will work. (I can reproduce that error if I mis-type `mget(table)`, which is using the *function* `table` and not the variable `tables`.)

Comment: It is likely referencing `data.table::tables` and failing.

Comment: this seemed plausible, so I changed the name... "one_1 <- Map(function(x, nm) copy(x)[, data_set := nm], mget(one), one)" and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Are all three actually `data.table`s, or is one (or more) a `data.frame` or other frame-like structure? If that's the case, perhaps `Map(function(x,nm) as.data.table(x)[,...],...,...)`.

Comment: Does `mget(tables)` or `mget(one)` (whichever you're currently using) work on the console without `Map`?

Comment: I was able to get this to work. My mistake. I was using it on a list that resulted from a previous lapply by accident. If I use it on the original list (as listed in my question) it works! But is there a way to get it to work on a list of data tables that results from a previous lapply? Would I need to alter the list prior to plugging it in?

Comment: Replace `mget(tables)` with the list previously generated, I'd think.

Comment: and also `lapply(tables, function(x) get(x)[, data_set := x])`